# cryptsetup - how does it print prompt bypassing stdout/stdin redirection?

Tags: file-descriptors

I just noticed that no matter which `cryptsetup` FDs are forwarded to `/dev/null` it still shows prompt for password. For example this still shows prompt:

`cryptsetyp luksOpen /dev/sdXY name >/dev/null 2>/dev/null`

How can you display in terminal message that cannot be redirected to file using standard redirection?

I'd like to get such functionality in bash script as I use stdout to return result to mother script but I'd still like to display interactive prompt - is it possible to do so using bash?

Comment: You're asking for an explanation, so a solution wouldn't address that. However, if you want to circumvent password input from terminal and force `cryptsetup` to read the password from standard input, use the `--key-file=-` option. This however won't strip trailing newline characters like it does for terminal password sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, It writes directly to `/dev/tty` (at any rate, you can get the same behavior)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# set up the new file descriptor
exec 3> /dev/tty

# test
echo "Stdout"
echo "Stderr" >&2
echo "Directly to tty" >&3
```

alternatively, you can simply do:

```
echo "Directly to tty" >/dev/tty
```

---

```
$ ./foo.sh >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
Directly to tty
```

`read` still works if you do this.

---

The exec is required to keep the redirection for the duration of the present shell.

A redirection on a simple command:

```
$ echo yes       3>file
```

lasts while the command is being executed. Once the command (echo in this example) ends, the shell removes the redirection and reverts back to the "present shell" execution environment.

A:

```
$ 3>file
```

is still a "simple command" where the command executed is "none", the redirection will not live for long.

Instead in:

```
$ exec 3>file
```

the exec replaces the "present shell" with a new one which includes the redirection. That makes the redirection stay alive for as long as the "present shell" exists. That could be undone (well, actually close fd 3) with:

```
$ exec 3>&-
```

Comment: what does `exec 3> /file` do? In a sense why there's eval.

Comment: It sets up the new file descriptor. Editing to clarify.

Comment: I mean why not just `3> /file` without `exec`.

Comment: I haven't the foggiest idea. It just doesn't work.

Comment: Exec is required because it's part of the shell syntax (e.g. run `help exec` in bash).  Normally a redirection only affects a single command's file descriptors.  You are redirecting *the shell's* file descriptors, which is a distinct operation.

Answer (score 6):

If you `strace` it, you will probably see that it uses `/dev/tty` directly.

```
...
open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR)                = 6
ioctl(6, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
write(6, "Enter passphrase for .......: ", 30) = 30
ioctl(6, SNDCTL_TMR_CONTINUE or TCSETSF, {B38400 opost isig icanon -echo ...}) = 0
...
```

In the source code (`utils_crypt.c`):

```
static int interactive_pass(const char *prompt, char *pass, size_t maxlen,
                long timeout)
{
[...]
        /* Read and write to /dev/tty if available */
        infd = open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR);
        if (infd == -1) {
                infd = STDIN_FILENO;
                outfd = STDERR_FILENO;
        } else
                outfd = infd;

        if (tcgetattr(infd, &orig))
                goto out_err;
```

So it tests for `/dev/tty` by opening it, and if that works it uses that. If it fails, it falls back to regular stdin, stdout, and then you wouldn't see the prompt anymore.

As for the `/dev/tty`, it's the terminal of the process, for more detail see `man 4 tty`.

Comment: Relevant xkcd: https://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: @Blacksilver I wouldn't say it's bad practice. It probably has something to do with security. After all it's really critical app security wise. The harder it is to hijack output the better.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'm just doing my obligatory duty.

Comment: And now I don't know why exactly did they use tty directly and what are security implications and I can't find the answer. My whole day is ruined now in blind desire for useless knowledge...

Comment: @Blacksilver: Goto is required in languages like C which don't have C++ destructors nor the `try`/`finally` of higher-level languages.  If you don't use goto, you have to duplicate your cleanup logic, which is messy and error-prone.